# Add Facebook Widget to Wordpress

Tags: facebook, widget, wordpress

First I know there are literally hundreds of facebook widgets that we can use in Wordpress and I have tried about half and they all work fine for a facebook profile page but none work with a "Business" page.  Most require an app id etc.  From what I have found the Business page does not have these, or at least I cannot find one.

Does anyone know is there a plugin that allows a "Business Page" live feed to be added to wordpress website?

Answer (score 1):

You will need an App ID.

Just go there and click on "create an application" : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
Then, enter whatever you want for name and namespace, and you'll have your App ID.

Comment: OK I tried the link and all it does is take me back to the facebook page.  Remember this is not a profile page for friends and family.  This is a business page where anyone can "Like" us.  I am new to this type of page and it is completely different than what I am used to.  Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: _“all it does is take me back to the facebook page”_ – you’ll need to _verify_ your account with Facebook before you can access that page.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I would like to give you a fuller explanation, the best thing to do is follow this link and use their template:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

You can use this to broadcast the 'activity' of your page on your site (it will generate the coding for you).